# Receive scrollViewDidScroll and UIGestureRecognizer touch event simultaneously

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIScrollView with a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to it.

On drag, I want to trigger the gesture recognizer, or `scrollViewDidScroll`, or sometimes both in a single drag. The gesture recognizer, however, steals the touch event, so the scrollview can't scroll.

Is there a way to send a single touch event to `scrollViewDidScroll` *and* the gesture recognizer?

(I tried subclassing the scrollview and overriding `gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer,
 shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer)`, with no effect, I assume because `scrollViewDidScroll` doesn't rely on a gesture recognizer.)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `collectionView` has a `panGestureRecognizer` property. Problem solved.